# i18n.js Unable to resolve "make-plural" from Pluralization.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, internationalization

I have a react native app and I am using expo.

I want to translate my mobile app so I am going to use expo-localization and i18n-js which I have installed following in the [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization/#complete-example).

Then I import it in my App.js as so:

```
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";
import i18n from "i18n-js";
```

I have also tried importing it this way :

```
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";
import { I18n } from "i18n-js";
```

but when importing i18n I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve "make-plural" from "node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/Pluralization.js"
```

In my package.json I have the following versions:

```
"i18n-js": "^4.2.3",
"expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 18):

Remember to also extend `expo/metro-config`

```js
 const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
 const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
 
 // Adds support for `mjs` files 
 config.resolver.sourceExts.push('mjs' ); 
 
 module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 16):

I was able to use `i18n-js` 4.2.3 by editing my metro config.

If I understand correctly, I think the problem is that `make-plural` includes some source files that Metro doesn't pick up by default.  You can fix this by making sure the extension is included in the `resolver.sourceExts` setting in your `metro.config.js` like so:

```
const defaultSourceExts = require('metro-config/src/defaults/defaults').sourceExts
const sourceExts = [ 'jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'svg', 'd.ts', 'mjs' ].concat(defaultSourceExts)

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    sourceExts
  },
}
```

I think I'm probably adding some duplicates to the list there, but this is what's working for me at the moment.

Comment: It worked for me. Specifically I had to add the `mjs` extension.

Comment: Also worked for me! Great work!

Comment: Using the default metro.cofig.js structure, just adding `config.resolver.sourceExts.push("mjs");` before the `module.exports = config;` will do the job.

Comment: I see `metro.config.js` mentioned all over the place, but I don't have such a file in my expo project. I tried creating one with this code, but I assume it has to be referenced somewhere to have any effect.

Answer (score 12):

make a downgrade to

"i18n-js": "4.2.0"

it started to use make-plural on the latest version
https://github.com/fnando/i18n/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 4):

This is the better workaround:
add this line before the export in the metro.config.js

```
config.watcher.additionalExts.push('mjs', 'cjs');
module.exports = config;
```

make-plural relies on support for resolving some extensions, which Metro supports by default but Expo overrides.

Comment: Now I get the error non-std C++ exception. Tried to delete node_modules and reinstall, npm start with --reset-cache